# Does the term “gay” refer to bi-sexuality as well, or is it explicitly referring to homo-sexuality?

Tags: terminology, sexual-minorities

The reason I am asking is because I am touching upon answering a question elsewhere which would debunk the claim that said person is gay on the grounds that he would most likely only be bi-sexual due to him having a wife and many children. However I do not know if this is correct.

I have done a little google research which does confirm that hetro-sexuality, homo-sexuality and bi-sexuality are three different categories. However it does not confirm whether or not the term "gay" in its modern usage refers to only homo-sexuality or both homo-sexuality and bi-sexuality.

Comment: For many people, "gay" doesn't even cover all *homosexuals* - just the *male* ones. [This site](https://www.apa.org/topics/lgbtq) is typical, referring to *those who identify as **lesbian, gay or bisexual**.* But human sexual orientation (physical and mental) is a complex continuum, which can't be fully covered by words and categories. It's the same as with the *visual spectrum*, where we could keep coining a new word for the intermediate colour between  two already-named shades, but we'd never have a name for every possible colour.

Comment: Someone's parental or marital status have no real bearing on their sexual orientation.

Comment: I imagine there are regional differences. Where I live, which has a large __gay__ community, the tern "gay" is used for any same sex attraction, including bisexuals. The term's idiomatic usage predates the transgender movement (which I would say separated from "queer" in the mid-90s), so "gay" tends not to cover transgendered, who are usually heterosexual in a purely physical way.

Comment: Aside: Even if you determine that gay means homosexual and not bisexual, the fact that the man was married to a woman and had kids with her does not mean he is bisexual and does not mean he is not homosexual. The explanation of that is way beyond the scope of ELU SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people make a distinction between *gay* and *bisexual*:

> **Monosexual**: People who are attracted to only one sex or gender. People who self-identify as straight, lesbian, or *gay*. — [pct.edu](https://www.pct.edu/files/imported/campuslife/studentactivities/docs/lgbtq-terms-and-definitionsPSU.pdf)

The people who don’t make a distinction tend to believe that anyone not completely heteronormative is gay: for example that [bisexuality isn’t real](https://www.out.com/news-opinion/2015/8/31/mark-simpson-rise-fall-monosexuality) or [asexuals must be (closeted) gays](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Asexuality). (This is, of course, offensive to people who identify as these orientations, and it’s something believed by fewer and fewer people as time goes by.)

Both *bisexual* and *gay* have some variation in meaning. *[Bisexual](https://www.rollingstone.com/culture/culture-features/whats-the-real-difference-between-bi-and-pansexual-667087/)* can refer to a specific non-monosexual orientation (attraction to both sexes) or to all non-monosexual orientations (as a synonym to pansexual, which includes attraction to trans/nonbinary people). *Gay* is sometimes used as a term for only men (as the counterpart to *lesbian*), a term for both gay men and/or women, and sometimes a term that’s even broader (as in *gay rights*).

Still, it’s important to recognize that there are terms beyond *gay* and *bisexual*. The medical field tends to use [MSM](https://www.health4men.co.za/queer-talk/04/18/what-is-msm/) (men who have sex with men), which includes gay and bisexual men, and also *heterosexual* men (its female counterpart being WSW). This is the significance of “self-identify” in the first quote, as many people who engage in such behaviors still identify as straight.

Answer (score 0):

The term *gay*, as used in everyday contexts, is not very precise.  If we are told that somebody is gay, and no further information is provided, we should not assume that the person is exclusively gay; being gay is logically compatible with one's having had some heterosexual experiences in one's life. The boundary between being gay and being bisexual (and the analogous boundary between being bisexual and being straight) is not a matter of one's having had some precise percentages of sexual experiences of this or that kind. Rather it's a matter of the role that these experiences play in one's life: it's a matter of whether the sexual attractions of one kind feel closer to the core of one's being than the sexual attractions of other kinds. That's not something that can be easily ascertained by an outside observer, which is why it is often said that being gay/bisexual/straight is a matter of **identifying** as gay/bisexual/straight rather than of some precise objective criteria.

It should also be noted that there are some contexts in which the term *gay* may incidentally cover even those who explicitly identify as bisexual. For example, if it is said that gay rights are respected in a particular community, it will be reasonable to assume that the rights of bisexuals are respected in it as well.